# How does one rewrite a Vector Equation in New Basis, specifically TNB Frame?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

I would like to sweep a closed parametric curve, lets say a tilted ellipse,
Curve #1:   r(v)=(2cos(v),sin(v),cos(v))
around an open space curve, lets say an elliptic helix,
Curve #2 :  r(u)=(10cos(u),5sin(u),(u)).
Can I rewrite Curve #2 as a function of (u,v) so that binormal, normal,
and tangent vectors of Curve #2 are used as the x,y,and z axis, respectively, of Curve #1?
This function of (u,v) would generate a surface, which is my objective.
It is assumed that Curve #2 is a smooth curve, but the magnitudes of its
T, N, and B vectors are not necessarily constant.

Comment: If the magnitudes are not constant, what are the vectors? Honestly, your question makes no sense. Define “sweep around,” for starters.

Comment: As a circle is swept around a helix to create a spring.

Comment: That only will make sense if the curve replacing the circle is still a planar curve, which yours is. Fix axes for that plane and use a parametrization where $N$ and $B$ replace the unit vectors for those axes.

Comment: Your comment is not making sense. Please read the question.

Comment: Well, since your question didn’t make sense, I interpreted based on your helix/spring.  How can you reparametrize curve 2 with two variables? As you point out, that gives a surface. Perhaps you should edit to show how you work out the helix/circle example.

Comment: I must be wording this question poorly, because curve #1 need not be planar. For each point along curve #2, there is a TNB frame. I want to construct curve #1 in that frame with T as the Z axis, N as the Y axis, and B as the X axis.

Comment: So you want to take $(2\cos v) B(u) + (\sin v) N(u) + (\cos v) T(u)$. But for this to be well-defined, you of course *must* take the usual orthonormal Frenet frame; you can't be talking about changing the lengths of the basis vectors.

Comment: Yes, Mr. Shifrin, for lack of a better way to describe it, sort of a seashell surface. In order to better understand the representation in your last comment,  I believe I'll spend some time viewing some of your videos on the subject.

Comment: Sorry, no videos on differential geometry. There's a text you can download for free, but my students never took videos of that course.